# Matplotlib imshow - Change default colour normalisation

Tags: python, matplotlib, normalization, imshow

I have consistently had problems with my colour maps when using `imshow`; some colours seem to just become black. I have finally realised that `imshow` seems to, by default, normalise the matrix of floating point values I give it.

I would have expected an array such as `[[0,0.25],[0.5,0.75]]` to display the appropriate colours from the map, corresponding to those absolute values but the 0.75 will be interpreted as a 1. In the extreme case, an N x N array of 0.2 (for example), would just produce one big black square, rather than whatever one would expect 0.2 to correspond to in the colour map (perhaps a 20% grey).

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour? It is particularly annoying when custom colour maps have many discontinuities; a small change in scale could cause all the colours to completely change.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Just specify `vmin=0, vmax=1`.

By default, `imshow` normalizes the data to its min and max. You can control this with either the `vmin` and `vmax` arguments or with the `norm` argument (if you want a non-linear scaling).

As a quick example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[0, 0.25], [0.5, 0.75]]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(data, cmap=plt.get_cmap('hot'), interpolation='nearest',
               vmin=0, vmax=1)
fig.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: My life is complete! This has nagged me for too long. Hope this helps somebody else.

Comment: It did. I've been searching the hell out of the www. To figure out the behaviour of imshow.

Comment: @DeeWBee Yes. From the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=matshow#matplotlib.pyplot.matshow): _With the exception of fignum, keyword arguments are passed to imshow()_

Comment: Actually, "vmin and vmax don't normalize the data, they clamp it". This was given in a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31234563/3797285).

Comment: `colorbar` that's what I was looking for :D

Answer (score 0):

You can also update `vmin` and `vmax` after an `imshow` call through the [`Normalize`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Normalize.html) object defined on the image. `Normalize` objects define `autoscale()` method which can update `vmin` and `vmax`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[0, 0.25], [0.5, 0.75]]

im = plt.imshow(data, cmap='hot')
plt.colorbar(im)
im.norm.autoscale([0, 1])
#                 ^^^^^^    <---- smaller value -> vmin; greater value -> vmax
```

Also `clim()` could be used to update `vmin`/`vmax` of the current image.

```py
im = plt.imshow(data, cmap='hot')
plt.colorbar(im)
plt.clim(0, 1)
```

[image]

On a side note, images can also be accessed via `images` property on the Axes instance, i.e. `im = plt.gca().images[0]`.