# Disabling scientific notation of imshow colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, imshow

For some reason, I can't find a way to turn off the scientific notation of the colorbar for the following plot:

[image]

I've tried using `powerlimits`:

```
ylabels = ['0:00', '03:00', '06:00', '09:00', '12:00', '15:00', '18:00', '21:00']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(27, 7))

cax1 = ax.imshow(df7, origin='lower', cmap='viridis', interpolation='none', aspect=4)
ax.set_xticklabels(label, fontsize = 12)
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(df7.columns)))

major_ticks = np.arange(0, 24, 3)
ax.set_yticks(major_ticks)
ax.set_yticklabels(ylabels, fontsize = 12)


fig.autofmt_xdate()


cb = plt.colorbar(cax1,fraction=0.046, pad=0.04)
cb.formatter.set_powerlimits((0, 8))
cb.update_ticks

plt.tight_layout()

ax.set_aspect(0.5)
fig.suptitle('November 2016 Normalized Pressure Data $[mbar]$',fontsize=15)
fig.tight_layout(pad = 1)

plt.show()
```

I've seen the similar question about formatting the colorbar, but here the question is how to format it for **disabling** the scientific notation!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scientific notation colorbar in matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25983218/scientific-notation-colorbar-in-matplotlib)

Comment: The question is different, but the answer should solve this problem too.

Comment: I need to disable it rather then enabling it, I don't see how this can work. thanks

Comment: Did you try the answer, or at least read it? Enabling and disabling something often works through the same command or parameter. In this case the key is to set the `format` option of the color bar. (note the second, less up-voted answer for a one-line solution)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution myself:

using these lines:

```
fmt = '%1.2f'
cb = plt.colorbar(cax1,fraction=0.046, pad=0.04, format = fmt)
```

and removing the line:

```
cb.formatter.set_powerlimits((0, 8))
```