# how to prevent plt imshow from normalize image

Tags: matplotlib, colors, imshow, normalize

Let's say i have an image where maximum value is 1 and minimum is 0.8 (very brighty image).

when i use `plt.imshow(image)` i expect to see high intensity image, but for some reason i still see black, that means that plt.imshow normalize the range `[0.8,1]` to be `[0,1]`

how can i see the image without this normalization process?

for example, here is my image:
[image]

and min value is 0.57, where max value is 1. so why there is black in the image..?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [matplotlib imshow - default colour normalisation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22121239/7758804)

Comment: `plt.imshow(image, vmin=0, vmax=1)`?

Comment: Much easier than i thought. Thank you!